# Ngrx polling effects stops working second time

Tags: angular, ngrx

When we start polling everything works as expected. Once we stop and start again $continueRefreshStudents stops working.  Please check the stackblitz example.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Start Polling (check console logs, polling continues )
2. Stop Polling
3. Start Polling 2nd time (This time polling doesn't continue)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-polling2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstate%2Fapp.effects.ts

Answer (score 1):

When you use `takeWhile` it completes the observable in your effect once the stop polling changes the `isPollingActive` to false. ngrx does not create a new effect each time you start the polling so the subsequent `getDataSuccess` actions effects don't happen. You can change your `takeWhile` to `filter` that way you just ignore the effects when `isPollingActive` is false.

I'm not sure however that this is the best approach, an action that has an effect that triggers the same action to happen again. I feel like it would be less confusing to have the start action create an `interval` which could fire a continue action and the stop action stop the `interval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move `takeWhile` to the inner observable (within `mergeMap`) pipe to resolve this issue because in this case, it will complete the inner observable, not the main effect's observable once the `isPollingActive` is changed:

```
public continuePolling$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(appActions.getDataSuccess),
    tap(data => console.log('app effect continue polling')),
    takeWhile(() => this.isPollingActive),
    delay(2000),
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.appDataSurvice.getData().pipe(
        switchMap(data => {
          return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)];
        }),
        catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err))),
        takeWhile(() => this.isPollingActive), // check again incase this has been unset since delay
      )
    )
  )
);
```